# How can I select for an input and a textarea?

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

```
        $('input.update-grid', $form)
            .each(function () {
                var id = this.id.replace('modal', '');
                $('#input' + id).val(this.value)
            })
```

I would like this to also select for textareas that have a class of upgrade-grid.  Is there a way that I can do this without making another selector and code?

Also if I want to set the text in a textarea is that just set in the same way as an input with .val()?

Comment: `$('.update-grid', $form).each...`?

Comment: But I have different code if it's a select.

Comment: In that case you can code `$('.update-grid:not(select)', $form).each..` or use adeneo's suggested selector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('input.update-grid, textarea.update-grid', $form)
```

Or if no other element tags have that class:

```
$('.update-grid', $form)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just select by the class name.

```
$('.update-grid', $form).each(function () {
   var id = this.id.replace('modal', '');
   $('#input' + id).val(this.value);
})
```